# How can I be a voter

Tags: discussion

How can I be a voter. I want to thank the persons who helped me, but I don't how? If you would have already read my message you surely would know!

Answer (score 7):

You have to contribute to the site, and gain reputation through good answers and good questions.  That is the only way you will gain the privileges you want - to cast votes.  There's two separate permissions levels though for casting votes:

- You can [upvote things once you've gained 15 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up).
- You can [downvote things once you've gained 125 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Any votes you try and cast without the reputation to cast the votes will be recorded in the database, and there's an obscure way to access statistics.  However, you won't influence the reputation of anyone nor will your votes actually show up on the front-end for other users to see until you have those privileges.

However, you can still comment on your own posts and answers to questions you've posted, so you can probably thank users that way... at least until the "thank you" comments are removed during regular cleanup processes.

Comment: Also, votes cast by users who don't have enough rep to affect the score are still recorded in the database and statistics including them are [available in an obscure corner of the site](https://askubuntu.com/tools/post-feedback/summary?filter=year)